# POSN number thoery camp 1 test number 2

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Prove that there is no prime number $p$ and $q$ such that $p^2+2023pq$ is a square number.

I try to prove this by using contradiction

Assume $p^2+2023pq$ has a square number

Therefore, there is $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $p^2+2023pq=n^2$ or $n^2-p^2=2023pq$ or $(n-p)(n+p)=2023pq$

**Case 1** $n$ is even and $p$ is even

Since $p$ is an even prime number,

Therefore, $p=2$

$(n-2)(n+2)=2023(2)(q)=4046q$

Since n is even

Therefore, $n-2$ is even and $n+2$ is even

Therefore, $2\mid (n-2)$ and $2\mid (n+2)$

Therefore, $4\mid (n-2)(n+2)$

Since $4\mid (n-2)(n+2)$ and $(n-2)(n+2)=4046q$

Therefore, $4\mid 4046q$

Since $2\mid 4046$ and $4\nmid 4046$

Therefore, $2\mid q$

Since $q$ is prime and $2\mid q$

Therefore, $q=2$

$(n-2)(n+2)=n^2-4=4046(2)=8092$

$n^2=8096$

Since $8096=2^2\cdot$

**Case 2** $n$ is odd and $p$ is odd

From $n^2-p^2=2023pq$, therefore $q$ is even

Since

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.

Comment: Ok, I will edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, prove $p\ne q$ by contradiction: If $p=q$, then $p^2+2023pq=2024p^2$, which cannot be a square (do you see why?)

Next, $p^2+2023pq=n^2 \Rightarrow p\mid n \Rightarrow n^2=p^2m^2$.

But $(p^2+2023pq=p^2m^2) \land (p\ne q) \Rightarrow p\mid 2023$ (do you see why?)

$2023=7\cdot 17^2$, therefore $p\in \{7,17\}$

So the general problem reduces to two specific problems: $$7^2+7^2\cdot 17^2q=n^2 \\17^2+7\cdot 17^3q=n^2$$
Case 1: $7^2+7^2\cdot 17^2q=n^2=7^2m^2$. Then $17^2q=m^2-1=(m-1)(m+1)$. Here the problem is to find two numbers which differ by $2$ but only have $17,17,q$ as factors among them. Neither $(17,17q)$ nor $(289,q)$ afford a solution.

Case 2: $17^2+7\cdot 17^3q=n^2=17^2m^2$. Then $7\cdot 17q=m^2-1=(m-1)(m+1)$. Here the problem is to find two numbers which differ by $2$ but only have $7,17,q$ as factors among them. Neither $(7,17q)$ nor $(17,7q)$ nor $(119,q)$ afford a solution.

No solutions exist.